# How to add custom plugin in telerik app builder app

Tags: asp.net, cordova, telerik-appbuilder

I have needed to add custom plugin into app for refresh gallery while image is download by user.

**Plugin: https://github.com/guinatal/refreshgallery**

I have already tried to added above plugin in my telerik app but not add properly.So,please give proper suggestion to how to add custom plugin in telerik app.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are full instructions on how to do this in the docs: http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/using-plugins/using-custom-plugins/add-custom-plugins